# CSS - div without content won't get a percentage width

Tags: css, width, percentage

As you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/2Qu9r/

The div if has no content won't get `20% width`, while if i put some content inside it gets the width

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is there, it just doesn't have a `height`.

Give `.dd` a height of `10px` and you'll see that it will show up.

eg

```
.dd {
  width:20%;
  height:10px;
  background:red;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CJBG/)**

If you look at the element in a browser console, you will see that it will be something like:

```
120px x 0
```

This means that it's `120px` wide but `0` in height.

`&nbsp;` is a blank character, but a character nonetheless. So obviously, it has a height. This means that `120px x 0` is now `120px x 20px`. That is why it's visible with a 'blank' character in it, but not visible with no content in.

(`120px` & `20px` are just example measurements)

Comment: Beat me to it. Correct. +1

Comment: Cool solution mate! i think i'm gonna accept it in few minutes! thanks a lot

Comment: also it works like for mistery could be great to know why the hack it works using height :D